# How to pre-fill select shipping method dropdown on step2 of shopify checkout page?

Tags: shopify

I guess the title pretty much explains what I want to do.

The thing is we have to provide some options based on the shipping method, so we developed a custom app for that,and provided the options on the checkout page.(Screenshot below)

[image]

Now when the user clicks on checkout and goes to the Shopify checkout page, he has to select the shipping method again on step 2 of the checkout page.

[image]

So is there a way to prefill the selected shipping method based on the selection made by user??

Answer (score 2):

You cannot program checkout with your own code. So the short answer is probably not.

Comment: I dont want to programmatically checkout, I just want to be able to preselect the shipping method dropdown..

Comment: As mentioned, you cannot program checkout and by that I meant you cannot use your own Javascript to select a shipping option element. You cannot do anything but skin checkout with CSS. Some people have said you can inject JS using the analytics snippet. Maybe that will work for you too.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact issue.  Our shop offers free local delivery, or FedEx shipping.  If the user selects FedEx shipping on the cart page, "free local delivery" was selected by default on the Shopify checkout page.

I worked around this by creating a bogus product in Shopify called "free delivery".  I then used the Shopify cart API to add this item to the user's cart if the user selected local delivery.  I set the weight on the "free delivery" product to 1000 lbs.  I then set up the "free local delivery" shipping method to be valid for 1000 - 9999 lbs.  Regular FedEx delivery is valid for orders up to 999 lbs.

It's a gross hack, but seems to work.  The user is still presented with the shipping method drop down on checkout, but only the correct option is available based on the delivery method chosen on the cart page.

Shopify Ajax API (for adding item to cart):
http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api

Note: I also had to go through some javascript contortions to add a new "updates[]" form field to the cart page when adding the bogus free shipping item to the cart.  Without this field, Shopify complained of receiving the wrong number of quantity updates when submitting the cart form.

Comment: hah, thats clever. and probably still the only way to do it. i cant find anything more reasonable at least.

Comment: Almost 10 years later, this is still the most straightforward way to do it. Shopify still lacks on a very basic feature every e-commerce should have implemented by default.